# Android alternative to LibreVox

Tags: android, audiobook

I use LibreVox for listening to public-domain audiobooks. I appreciate that many titles are available free, but the quality of the Android app is poor.

Audible offers a much better user experience, but I only use it when I can't find a title at LibreVox, as Audible doesn't offer free audiobooks.

I've tried OverDrive, but the hassle of locating and checking out books is too much. So:

Is there an Android app that would offer:

- free public-domain audiobooks
- few defects
- easy navigation and search, general good user experience
- available on-demand (no checkout proceedures)

I'm willing to pay a few dollars for a decent app that does what LibreVox does better. I'm just not willing (at this time) to pay $14 for each book.

Comment: I'm not using AudioBooks myself – but while waiting for recommendations, be welcome to my list of available [Android apps for AudioBooks](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_music_folderplay#group_336).

Comment: "quality of the Android app" <- Please explain in more details. Crashes? Too many buttons to click? Audio difficult to hear? Slow?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul It's things like "sometimes if I stop listening in the middle of the chapter it thinks I finished and starts at the next chapter". Also basic navigation, search & discovery is clunky. Essentially I'm looking for less buggy and more polish.

Comment: Could you please make bullet points in the body of your question for each of those? Bugs and polish can mean very different things to different people.

Comment: What formats are these audio books in? If MP3, you can use VLC player. I use that all the time for listening to podcasts. One criterion it does *not* meet is maintaining position through a restart (it does so for video but not audio). It maintains position if you pull and re-insert the audio plug, though.

Comment: I have no idea the format of LibreVox books. Maintaining position is pretty essential for audio books, in any case.